# Dealing with NA values using Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp, na

I'm testing a piece of my code, which is shown below:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix testOutMat(const int& ncols, const int& nrows, const NumericVector& col_prob){

  //Store row and column positions
  NumericVector col_pos = no_init(nrows);
  NumericVector row_pos = no_init(nrows);

  int row_val;
  int nz_counter=0;
  for(int j=0; j<ncols; ++j){ 
    for(int i=0; i<nrows; ++i){
      row_val = R::rbinom(1,col_prob[j]);
      Rcout << "i,j: " << i << "," << j << std::endl;
      Rcout << "val: " << row_val << std::endl;
      if(row_val==1){ //if (i,j)th entry is a 1, save location
        row_pos[i] = i;
        col_pos[i] = j;
        nz_counter += 1;
      } else{ //assign as NA
        row_pos[i] = NA_REAL;
        col_pos[i] = NA_REAL;
      }
      Rcout << "row_pos[i]: " << row_pos[i] << std::endl;
      Rcout << "col_pos[i]: " << col_pos[i] << std::endl;
      Rcout << "num non-zeros: " << nz_counter << std::endl;
    }
  }

  NumericMatrix out = no_init(nz_counter,2);

  Rcout << "Printing output matrix" << std::endl;
  for(int i=0; i<nz_counter; ++i){
    if(!Rcpp::NumericVector::is_na(row_pos[i])){ 
      out(i,0) = row_pos[i];
      out(i,1) = col_pos[i];
    }
    Rcout << "row_pos[i]: " << row_pos[i] << std::endl;
    Rcout << "col_pos[i]: " << col_pos[i] << std::endl; 
  }

  return out;
}

/*** R
set.seed(1)
res <- testOutMat(ncols=5,nrows=5,col_prob = runif(20, 0.1, 0.2))
*/
```

From the output, I have that the entries `(i,j)={(0,0),(3,1)}` are non-zero, so that `res` should be a `2x2` matrix with `0 0` in the first row and `3 1` in the second. However, I get something very different:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   64 1024
[2,]    1    4
```

I suspect that this is due to how I'm handling `NA`s. The overall goal of the function is to generate the row and column indices for non-zero elements (generated by the call to `rbinom`).

I've tried debugging this for some time now and I can't seem to get a fix.

Comment: So, your objective is to: (1) `ncols` times, generate `nrows` binomial deviates, with the success probability differing by column; (2) store the row and column indices of "successes" (non-zero elements). Is that correct?         BTW, the problem here is that you're writing over `row_pos` and `col_pos` over and over again (`ncols` times) without any kind of keeping track of the prior result. That, coupled with your `no_init()` use, is what's causing the end result you see. I think the best solution is a complete refactoring, that's why I ask about your exact objectives

Comment: Yes you are right. I’ve had a long night and not thinking properly. I’ll look back over my code and edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're writing over `row_pos` and `col_pos` over and over again (`ncols` times) without any kind of keeping track of the prior result. That, coupled with your `no_init()` use, is what's causing the end result you see. We can change your code just a bit to ensure that `row_pos` and `col_pos` don't get overwritten:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix testOutMat(const int ncols, const int nrows,
                         const NumericVector& col_prob) {

    IntegerMatrix binomial_deviates(nrows, ncols);
    IntegerVector row_positions;
    IntegerVector col_positions;
    int nz_counter = 0;

    for ( int j = 0; j < ncols; ++j ) {
        binomial_deviates(_, j) = rbinom(nrows, 1, col_prob[j]);
        for ( int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i ) {
            if ( binomial_deviates(i, j) == 1 ) {
                row_positions.push_back(i);
                col_positions.push_back(j);
                nz_counter += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    IntegerMatrix out(nz_counter, 2);

    for ( int i = 0; i < nz_counter; ++i ) {
        out(i, 0) = row_positions[i];
        out(i, 1) = col_positions[i];
    }

    return out;
}

/*** R
set.seed(1)
res <- testOutMat(ncols=5,nrows=5,col_prob = runif(20, 0.1, 0.2))
*/
```

Result:

```
> set.seed(1)

> res <- testOutMat(ncols=5,nrows=5,col_prob = runif(20, 0.1, 0.2))
> res
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    3    1
```

Comment: Thank you. Your earlier comment helped me realize that I needed the auxiliary matrix (`binomial_deviates` in your code) and that the way 
way I was defining `row_positions` and `col_positions` would lead to cardinality `nrows x ncols`, not `nrows` as I had initially written. Could you comment also on differences in using `std::vector<int> row_positions` vs `IntegerVector row_positions`? Is one using up more memory than the other?

Comment: @stats134711 I have definitely not done a deep dive on all the differences in function and performance between `std::vector<int>` and `Rcpp::IntegerVector`; I *believe* I have read that the `push_back()` operation I use here will be *slightly* more efficient on an `std::vector<int>`, but I can't imagine it would make any practical difference in terms of execution time or memory used.